# How to customize shadow

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to change the appearance of `QCompleter` popup window. I have tried `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` but it's not working because that window has system shadow. And if I combine `DropShadowEffect` with the platform-dependent `WinApi` code to disable the system shadow widget, it does not show up at all.

Disabling system shadow example:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(popup()->winId());  
DWORD windowStyle = GetClassLongW(hWnd, GCL_STYLE);          
if(windowStyle & CS_DROPSHADOW)                              
{                                                            
    windowStyle ^= CS_DROPSHADOW;                            
    SetClassLongW(hWnd, GCL_STYLE, windowStyle);             
}
```

Qt 5.0.1 
gcc 4.7.2 
Windows 7 x64